# Elastics search Nest .net client hanging up on any request.

Tags: .net, elasticsearch, nest

Blocks forever and does not return nor posts connection status messages.  This is a code fragment that shows how I am connecting to the default port.  Connection was verified using Chrome browser.

```
    static void ConnectToElasticIndex(string name)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty (name))
            throw(new ArgumentNullException ("name"));

        var node = new Uri ("http://localhost:9200");

        var settings = new ConnectionSettings (
            node, 
            name
        ).SetConnectionStatusHandler(h=>
            _log.InfoFormat("Url: {0} | Method: {1} | Request: \n{2}",
            h.RequestUrl,
            h.RequestMethod,
                Encoding.UTF8.GetString(h.Request)));

        _client = new ElasticClient (settings);
```

Blocks here or on any call I make to the client.

```
        var res = _client.Raw.ClusterHealth();

        _log.Info(res.SuccessOrKnownError);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line of code

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetString(h.Request)
```

`Request` can be null such as in the case of the `ClusterHealth()` call and when that happens, the line will throw an exception. I'm not sure what behaviour you're seeing when you say blocking, but what you have above will throw a Null reference exception.

If you want to log requests then the following will work for requests that have a body and also ones that don't

```
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(
    node,
    name
)
.SetConnectionStatusHandler(response =>
{
    // log out the requests
    if (response.Request != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} \n{2}\n", response.RequestMethod.ToUpperInvariant(), response.RequestUrl,
            Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response.Request));
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}\n", response.RequestMethod.ToUpperInvariant(), response.RequestUrl);
    }
});
```

And if you also want to log out responses, you can use

```
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(
    node,
    name
)
.ExposeRawResponse(true)
.SetConnectionStatusHandler(response =>
{
    // log out the requests
    if (response.Request != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} \n{2}\n", response.RequestMethod.ToUpperInvariant(), response.RequestUrl,
            Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response.Request));
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}\n", response.RequestMethod.ToUpperInvariant(), response.RequestUrl);
    }

    if (response.ResponseRaw != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Status: {0}\n{1}\n\n{2}\n", response.HttpStatusCode, Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response.ResponseRaw), new String('-', 30));
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Status: {0}\n\n{1}\n", response.HttpStatusCode, new String('-', 30));
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Russ. Thanks for the advice.  Will definitely use that improved code. I added the status handler much later to see what is happening.  It is blocking indefinitely regardless.  I am going to try http call to see if it some security setting in the OS that is causing this.

Comment: @MarioBrenes - might be worth looking at firewall settings

Answer (score 0):

Very strange.  It is not blocking now.  It must be related to the OS TCP/IP.  This time, I restarted the compute and the Elastic node and VOILA!  It works.